# ¿Cómo convertir un String en su binario correspondiente en ASCII y viceversa?

Tags: java

Necesito convertir cada caracter de un String en el binario correspondiente en ASCII, por ejemplo:

```
String s = "KK";
```

En Hexadecimal sería 4B 4B, por lo tanto en binario sería 01001011 01001011.
Acá me pasaron éste código que sirve para convertir el string en hexadecimal:

```
String s = "K";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
System.out.println(bytesToHex(b));    


private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Pero no se como pasarlo a binario sin predefinir valores para cada caracter hexadecimal en una clase o método.

Es decir, en el mejor de los casos quisiera pasar el String directamente al binario que le corresponde en el código ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `toString()` de la clase `BigInt` tiene una sobrecarga para pasarle la base deseada. Si le pasas la base 2 te devuelve el `string` en binario:

> public String toString(int radix)
>
> Returns the String representation of this BigInteger in the given
>   radix. If the radix is outside the range from Character.MIN_RADIX to
>   Character.MAX_RADIX inclusive, it will default to 10 (as is the case
>   for Integer.toString). The digit-to-character mapping provided by
>   Character.forDigit is used, and a minus sign is prepended if
>   appropriate. (This representation is compatible with the (String, int)
>   constructor.)
>
> Parameters:
>       radix - radix of the String representation. Returns:
>       String representation of this BigInteger in the given radix

[Fuente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

Tendrías que hacer algo así. Primero obtener el [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) en base 16 y a continuación hacer el `toString()` a base 2 (binario). Tendrás que jugar con el formato para el padding de ceros a la izquierda (así funciona para 16 posiciones pero habría que hacer algo más estándar)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%16s", hexToBin("4B4B")).replace(' ', '0'));        
    }
    static String hexToBin(String s) {
      return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
    }
```

BigInteger no tiene limitación de tamaño (más allá de la impuesta por la propia memoria del ordenador)

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246326/convert-hexadecimal-string-hex-to-a-binary-string) 
Más [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean) sobre la limitación de tamaño: